# Why Java7 introduces AutoCloseable specially?

Tags: java, autocloseable

`AutoCloseable` is introduced in jdk1.7 and `Cloesable` is already in jdk1.5.

And According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

> The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed
>   at the end of the statement. Any object that implements
>   java.lang.AutoCloseable, **which includes all objects which implement
>   java.io.Closeable, can be used as a resource.**

So, the `Closeable` instance is already can be treated as a resource in `try-with-resources` statement. This is for sure, since `Closeable` extends from `AutoCloseable`.

My question is why java specially introduces `AutoCloseable` , why don't they only make Closeable to  be supported in `try-with-resources`, is there any other ways for AutoCloseable to be used except for `try-with-resources`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Closeable` is restricted to throw `IOException`, which may not be appropriate for some closeable but non-IO-bound resources.

`AutoCloseable` is declared to throw `Exception`, making it more general-purpose.

The API for `Closeable` can't be changed to throw `Exception` as that would be a breaking change, hence the new superinterface.

Additionally, as [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html#close--):

> Note that unlike the `close` method of `Closeable`, this close method is not required to be idempotent. In other words, calling this close method more than once may have some visible side effect, unlike `Closeable.close` which is required to have no effect if called more than once. However, implementers of this interface are strongly encouraged to make their close methods idempotent.

So while every `Closeable` is `Autocloseable`, the reverse is not true, and it would have been limiting to restrict try-catch-finally to the semantics of `Closeable`.

Comment: Thank you very much!!I think the first reason is more persuasive. It will be great if you can update your answer and give us an example of resource whose `close()` does not throws `IOException`.

Comment: @Jaskey: `ResultSet` is a good example, where `close()` throws `SqlException`.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two is that classes implementing `Closeable` must guarantee that invoking `close()` multiple times has no side-effects. There's no such restriction on `AutoCloseable`.

In practice this means that everything should be `Closeable` but those classes that would need to be retrofitted can choose the less restrictive `AutoCloseable`.